# Camel JMS : how to configure custom message listener when connecting to a topic

Tags: java, spring, jms, apache-camel, spring-jms

I need to define a route which reads message (has an xml) from a Topic and unmarshals it to a java bean.

Earlier i was using spring JmsTemplate for managing connectionFactory for the topic and my route looked something like this (and it worked fine)
The message converter essetially returns the `TextMessage` instance in the `fromMessage()` method

```
JaxbDataFormat dataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat();
dataFormat.setContextPath("com.somepath.xml");

from("jms:topic:myTopic?transacted=true&connectionFactory=myJmsConnectionFactory&messageConverter=#myMessageConverter")
 .transacted()
 .unmarshal(dataFormat)
 .routeId("myRouteId")
```

Now, instead of a JmsTemplate, i am using `org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer` to connect to this durable topic.

(Also because it supports asynchronous mode)

For this i wrote my own message listener which implements `javax.jms.MessageListener` and i read the message in `onMessage()`. But i cannot return a TextMessage from here like the way i used to do when is used JmsTemplate.

I don't know how can i configure this in the route definition so that it still supports unmarshalling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a lot of things and the solution is really simple, there is no need to use `org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer, instead, all we need to do is to define a connectionFactory which in my case was the myJmsConnectionFactory instance defined as the following in the spring xml

```
<bean id="myJmsConnectionFactory"        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="myJndiTemplate" />
            <property name="jndiName" value="TopicConnectionFactory" />
            <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
            <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
            <property name="cache" value="true" />
</bean>
```

This connection factory uses a jndi template which helps in the jndi look up of remote objects. This is defined as

```
<bean id="myJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
            <property name="environment">
                <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
                    <property name="location" value="file:///opt/test/jndi.properties" />
                </bean>
            </property>
</bean>
```

In the route definition, i just use this connection factory to lookup the remote topic. By default camel registers a message listener when you connect to a jms topic and you don't have to specify one (you can but i didn't need to :))

```
JaxbDataFormat dataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat();
dataFormat.setContextPath("com.somepath.xml");

from("jms:topic:myTopic?transacted=true&connectionFactory=myJmsConnectionFactory")
 .transacted()
 .unmarshal(dataFormat)
 .routeId("myRouteId")
```